# How to catch an event before Page_Load

Tags: c#, events, lifecycle

I have a recurrent problem in ASP ans its life cycle, which is to catch events BEFORE the Page_Load event raises.
For example, here i'm customizing a gridview, which inherits from the gridView class.
I add a dropdownlist to select a page to jump on (PageIndexChanged). Everything would be great, except that the SelectedIndexChanged Event of this dropdownlist is called after I render it (the grid and my dropdown are regenerated at each postback). So I cannot select the right value in it.

So my event is raised only at the second postback, I am always one postback late.

That dropdown is added on the RowCreated Event. I tried in other events but its whether too late or too early (not rendered if too late, missing elements if too early).

Any solution ?

PS: I found [this article](http://forums.asp.net/t/894051.aspx/1#989724) which could help me, but I'm not sur how to do it:

> Points to consider when making control or enheriting/extending:
>
> 1. You have to create any items that you want to raise events by overriding CreateChildControls where you call
>      base.CreateChildControls(), then do anything you want (ie add rows in
>      your case).
> 2. List item DataBinding the way you present is highly...non kosher.... You should simplify it by overriding DataBind() so that it
>      Clears children, then calls EnsureChildControls(), then adds the new
>      Rows... this way its nicely ViewStated, persisted, and event managed.
>      Much simpler.
> 3. List item Again: don't create your children too early either: Avoid creating child controls directly in OnInit, or onLoad. Its a
>      mistake. The best is to let the system call EnsureChildControls when
>      it needs to (it will in PreRender on first page load, and on PostBack,
>      if it had events for children, call it just after OnInit) ... At
>      worse, let OnInit, OnLoad call EnsureChildControls().

Answer (score 1):

The msdn page you are after is [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it has a helpful table telling you all the events which happen throughout the lifecycle of the page.

You will likely want one of the following (from the above link):

**PreInit**

Raised after the start stage is complete and before the initialization stage begins.

Use this event for the following:

- Check the IsPostBack property to determine whether this is the first time the page is being processed. The IsCallback and IsCrossPagePostBack properties have also been set at this time.
- Create or re-create dynamic controls.
- Set a master page dynamically.
- Set the Theme property dynamically.
- Read or set profile property values.

**Init**

Raised after all controls have been initialized and any skin settings have been applied. The Init event of individual controls occurs before the Init event of the page.

Use this event to read or initialize control properties.

**InitComplete**

Raised at the end of the page's initialization stage. Only one operation takes place between the Init and InitComplete events: tracking of view state changes is turned on. View state tracking enables controls to persist any values that are programmatically added to the ViewState collection. Until view state tracking is turned on, any values added to view state are lost across postbacks. Controls typically turn on view state tracking immediately after they raise their Init event.

Use this event to make changes to view state that you want to make sure are persisted after the next postback.

**PreLoad**

Raised after the page loads view state for itself and all controls, and after it processes postback data that is included with the Request instance.

Comment: *"I tried in other events but its whether too late or too early"*. I assumed he'd already seen that :)

Comment: @mattytommo - assumed makes an ass out of u and med. Wait, thats not right ;)

Comment: Haha, well they do say assumptions are the mother of all f*** ups :)

Comment: Yes, mattytommo is right, I tried in different state of the life cycle. There is always something wrong

Comment: @GuillaumeMartin - "Something wrong" is not a phrase that lends itself to people helping you solve the problem. With dynamic controls its usually that you've *created* them at the wrong point in the lifecycle. What ive shown above is all the events which occur before PageLoad. You should be looking at tutorials for dynamic controls in ASP.NET to work out your problem.

Comment: Now I generate my custom row in the OnDatabound event. The row is well created and always shown.
But the textbox in it has a textChanged event which not fires everytime

Answer (score 0):

Ok it finally seems I solved my problem thanks to the article I gave above,  [and this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/marcochila/archive/2007/09/28/gridview-a-great-control-to-extend.aspx/), and a lot of searching:

```
public class MyGridView : GridView
{
    TextBox txtSearch;

    protected override int CreateChildControls(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
    {
        int numRows = base.CreateChildControls(dataSource, dataBinding);

        // Create a new row
        GridViewRow rowSearch = base.CreateRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);

        //convert the existing columns into an array, initialize and then add the row to the previously created table
        DataControlField[] fields = new DataControlField[this.Columns.Count];
        this.Columns.CopyTo(fields, 0);
        this.InitializeRow(rowSearch, fields);

        TableCell cellSearch = new TableCell();
        rowSearch.Cells.Add(cellSearch);

        txtSearch = new TextBox();
        txtSearch.Text = this.SearchTextboxDefaultValue;
        txtSearch.ID = "txtSearch";
        txtSearch.AutoPostBack = true;
        txtSearch.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtSearch_TextChanged);
        cellSearch.Controls.Add(txtSearch);

        this.Controls[0].Controls.Add(rowSearch); // Controls[0] is a Table element

        return numRows;
    }

    protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string search = (sender as TextBox).Text;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // We fill in dt with results, and rebind it

        this.DataSource = dt;
        this.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And in the Page.cs:

```
private DataTable dt;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sampleDataTable();
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        myGrid.DataSource = dt;
        myGrid.DataBind();
    }
}

private void sampleDataTable()
{
    // Populate the dataTable
}
```

Thank you